# Why won't my environment variables load into my flask app?

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables

wasn't sure whether to post here in in linux but i'm having some trouble. I have a flask blog application that requires environment variables. I am accessing them using the os module like this:

```
import os
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

however when I do this I get a KeyError on the 'Secret key'. I am sure the environment variables have been set, permanently and i'm just really confused and I have been stuck with this problem for days now and really need some help. Sorry if I wasn't descriptive enough; if you need any more information just ask in the comments. Also, what is the difference between:

```
os.environ['env var']
```

and

```
on.environ.get('env var')
```

This is the apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  SetEnv SECRET_KEY secret_as_heck
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the python init

```
def create_app():    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] =os.environ['DB_URI']
    app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
    app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587
    app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
    app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = os.environ['MAIL_USERNAME']
    app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = os.environ['MAIL_PASSWORD']
```

Thanks

Comment: *How* have you set those environment variables?

Comment: I used export VARNAME=VARVALUE and then changed a few things in .profile / .bashrc. (it was a few weeks ago I did that so i don't remember the specifics) But when I do printenv after restarting putty, they are still there so they are set permanently.

Comment: Are  you certain that you've edited the .profile/.bashrc for the account that is running the app?

Comment: OK, how are you starting your server process? Are you doing it manually, or is there some kind of systemd/supervisor process that starts it up?

Comment: @BryanOakley I only have 1 user i'm pretty sure (not good with linux/ubuntu) it is root/sudo

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have a wsgi file that i believe is handling the calling of the process

Comment: No that's not what I asked. How is Flask being started?

Comment: @DanielRoseman not quite sure I know what you mean. I am using apache2 if that's what you're asking.

Comment: [How to set environment variables for your web apps (for SECRET_KEY etc)](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/environment-variables-for-web-apps/)

Comment: @jww I am not using a virtual environment I don't think

Answer (score 0):

In your Apache virtual host configuration add the variables like this

```
<VirtualHost hostname:80>
   ...
   SetEnv VARIABLE_NAME variable_value
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

The difference between `os.environ['env var']` and `on.environ.get('env var')` is that `.get(key)` will return `None` if the environment variable could not be found whereas `os.environ['env var']` raises `KeyError`.

Comment: This is still giving a KeyError. Should I still be accessing using os.environ?

Answer (score 0):

If your variable was defined indeed, you would've seen it in `os.environ`. One possible way to manually replicate the situation you are in is to define the variable in one terminal and to start python's virtualenv from another. I'd suggest going to the point from which you start your flask app, and double-check the environment variables.

Comment: python I start python repl and import os and print the os.environ['var']) i get key error

Comment: @Throupy could you copy the code where the variable is defined?

Comment: I added to the original post

Comment: and how do you start flask?

Comment: It is started by the apache2 automaticially I beleive.